# How do I get the original constructor for a HTML DOM class?

Tags: javascript, html

Another script I don't control is overwriting window.URL, how do I get the constructor?

Code I don't control:

```
URL = "not the constructor you seek";
```

My code:

```
var myUrl = new window.URL(someString);
```

is failing with *TypeError: URL is not a constructor*

Is there a way to get window.URL's original value? I have no way of running code that will reliably execute first, this is a somewhat hostile execution environment.

Comment: have you tried `top.URL()`? However, it probably points to the same thing...

Comment: what browser and version is the code failing?

Comment: If you can get an instance of whatever class you want to work with, you can probably grab its constructor fn via `theUrl.constructor`. Obviously doesn't necessarily help in all cases but could cover certain circumstances.

Comment: @Peter latest chrome, edge, firefox and safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script needs to execute in a hostile environment there isn't really anything you can do to guarantee that it will execute correctly.

With that said, some methods are "safer" (i.e. less likely to have been overwritten) than others.

One technique I've used in the past which might help you here is to access a clean `window` as a sandbox and run all your code from the context of that sandbox:

```
const sandbox = document.createElement('iframe')
sandbox.src = 'about:blank'
sandbox.style.display = 'none'
document.body.appendChild(sandbox)
const sandboxWindow = sandbox.contentWindow
console.log(new sandboxWindow.URL('http://example.com'))
```

Comment: Does `about:blank` always bypass CORS restrictions?

Comment: @Marie, that's a great question which I don't know the answer to. I know that you can't use this technique if the page is loaded in a sandboxed `<iframe>` (which is why this won't work as a stack snippet), but my understanding is that `about:blank` is a blank document without an origin so CORS is not an issue. [This older question seems relevant](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33386/3839).